# php exec change password in file

Tags: php, forms, sed, exec

I'm trying to make a simple input form to change a password in a config file. I believe I am pretty close but after trying for an hour to get the exec line below correct I believe I need some help.

```
# password in conf file
# $password = '12345';


<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['new_pass'])){
    exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/\$password=.*/\$password=\'".$_REQUEST['new_pass'].'\'/g')." include/conf.php");
    echo 'password changed';
}
?>

<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="new_pass" maxlength="59">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I'm fairly certain it is the ' quotations that are tripping me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, look at the syntax highlighting.

```
exec('sed -i ' . escapeshellarg('s/\$password=.*/\$password=\''.$_REQUEST['new_pass'].'\'/g')." include/conf.php");
```